# IDA Copy structure from one database instance to another

Tags: ida, decompilation, idapython

This question sounds rather simple, but I can't seem to find any option for this.

I'm basically re-creating another database instance of the same binary I already reversed and I want to copy some of the structures I previously created in the previous instance to my new fresh IDA database instance.
Is there any way of doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic way:

1. File-Produce File-[Dump typeinfo to IDC...](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/445.shtml)
2. In the other IDA instance, File-Script File..., choose file from step 1.

"New" way:

1. View-Subviews-Local Types (<kbd>Shift+F1</kbd>)
2. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>), Right click, Export to header

OR:

1+2. File-Produce File-[Create C header file...](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/141.shtml)

3. In the other IDA instance, first make sure Options-Compiler... settings are identical, then:

   3a. File-Load File-[Parse C header file...](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1367.shtml), choose file from previous steps. OR:
   3b. Open Local types, Ins, paste the contents of the header file (or individual structs if you need only specific ones).

P.S. second way does not copy struct attributes which cannot be represented in C (e.g. hex/decimal/binary/string representations, non-0-based pointers etc.)

Comment: Thank you @Igor for the detailed answer! Will give this a shot soon :)